# Array comparison failing for copied items

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nscopying

I am trying to compare two mutable arrays having my model objects. In one array I am creating the model objects as-is, where as in the other array I am creating a copy of the original object using `copyWithZone` (My models are subclass of `NSObject`). However when I compare, It is always failing even though I did not change anything.

I printed both the arrays just to check and both seem to have the same objects.

Will `isEqualToArray` not work on copied items?

Can someone point out where I am going wrong? Or if there is any other way to do this comparison?

Comment: Do you have custom object inside the array?

Comment: Have you implemented `isEqual:` and `hash`? The default implementation does not work for custom objects.

Comment: Show the implementation of `copyWithZone:`, `isEqual:` and `isEqualTo:`.

Comment: "Or if there is any other way to do this comparison" ... have you made any effort to search for another way ? literally can't count how many answers to this there are on stackoverflow already

Comment: Can you paste your code ??

Answer (score 0):

When comparison involved between object, then `isEqual` and `hash` methods should be overridden. isEqualToArray will return true only if object pass `isEqual` test. So please implement `isEqual` and `hash` methods in your modal object. After that you will able to use `isEqualToArray` method.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest for you to override the isEqual: method on both NSObject subclasses in a format similar to the example below.

Assume there is object of class Object and Compared Object. Both contain properties called propA (nsnumber) and propB (nsstring). This will work even if the two objects are of the same subclass.

```
-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[ComparedObject class]]) {
        if ([self.propA isEqualToNumber:object.propA] && [self.propB             
            isEqualToString:object.propB]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Then, you can simply iterate through the contents of the arrays and check each object in the example method shown below.

```
- (BOOL) isArrayEqual:(NSMutableArray *)fArray compareTo:(NSMutableArray *)sArray {
    for (CustomObject *obj in fArray) {
        NSUInteger index = [fArray indexOfObject:obj];
        if (![obj isEqual:[sArray objectAtIndex:index]]) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```